# Get the list of members in a JXTA peergroup

Tags: java, p2p, jxta

Im just wondering is there a way to get the list of active or online (members)peers who have joined to a particular peergroup in JXTA ?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No not really. The issue is that the connectivity and reachability of peers in a P2P networkis transient. Any information you might be able to get would quickly degrade in time.

If you want an idea of the connected peers, you could have them sent "hello word" and "bye world" messages when they connect and leave. However, this won't cover for all cases. Sometimes, if you don't get an answer from a peer after a chosen delay, you must assume it has gone offline.